# What's the procedure for obtaining a Tourist Visa for USA?

Tags: visas, usa, romania

I am a student in Romania and I want to travel to usa this summer. I need to know what is the procedure and what paperwork I need to fill in for my request.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain a tourist visa, you must first fill out the related forms published on the website of the embassy of the United States of America, and then take a visa interview where you will find out whether or not your visa is approved.
the process is relatively easy.

You can find more information on the embassy's website: https://ro.usembassy.gov/

I hope that was useful for you
Good luck :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was really helpful. I'll check the website and proceed with the paperwork immediatly. Have a nice day! :*

Comment: This reads like an AI generated answer, and doesn't really give any additional information.  The OP asked what procedure and paperwork was required, and this answer basically just says there's a procedure and some paperwork but doesn't give any additional info